# How can I maintain the "disabled" property when the view is rendered after form validation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an Edit view form which uses the fieldset disabled property to initially gray out the form. The user must click an Edit button to enable the form and modify its values.

When the form is submitted and the Edit view is rendered because the form didn't validate, the form goes back to being disabled. I would like the form to stay enabled so the user sees what's wrong with the form.

Snippet of my edit view file:

```
  %fieldset{:disabled => false}
    = render 'shared/form_fields', f: f
```

Snippet of the Jquery I used:

```
    $('.panel-body, button.edit').click ->
        if $('fieldset').prop('disabled') is true
            $('fieldset').prop('disabled', false)
            $("button.save, button.cancel").show()
            $("button.edit").hide()

    $("button.cancel").click ->
        $('fieldset').prop('disabled', true)
        $("button.save, button.cancel").hide()
        $("button.edit").show()
```

Comment: Are there any trigger after the submit action? Maybe the form renders again and sets the field to disabled

Comment: @cmramseyer I have this form's action set to another controller action (not the default Update action). Not sure if that would affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this JQuery and it worked:

```
    if $('.alert').length
        $('fieldset').prop('disabled', false)
```